# Can't create multiple CassandraOperations without configuring keyspace？

Tags: cassandra

I only have a yaml file, configured two cassandra address, but I follow the Spring-data for cassandra in the document, created two cassandraConfig, of course, their names are not the same, but when I start my application, reported an error create bean wrong I do not know what to do now. I don't know what to do now. The requirement is to write the same data to two different cassandra datapaths.

Comment: I don't think that Spring Data will let you write data to two different clusters.  Are the two nodes in the same cluster?

Comment: I don't think it's in the same cluster, the config file has two different ip addresses and they don't specify the clustername and keyspacename.

Comment: Run a `nodetool status` on one of the nodes.  That should tell you for sure.  As for the error, Spring Data will fail to "create bean" when it cannot connect.  This could mean anything from bad IP address, nodes not running, or incorrect username & password.  Basically, make sure the cluster is running and that you can connect to it using CQLSH.  That's a good first step.

Comment: Also, it is commonplace to use multiple IP addresses in the driver config when connecting to Cassandra.

Comment: And specifying a keyspace shouldn't matter for connecting.

Comment: thank you，you are right ，colleague  give me prod link，this is causing the connection to fail, spring data 2.X version supports multiple datasources, just create multiple different cassandraTemplates and add @Autowired @Qualifier("your bean name") when you use them